# text wrapping in two column table

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table in which a text can automatically adjust itself as some of my text hide out of border page. Below is code of my draft. Kindly solve the issue for me. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{url}  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}
\usepackage[sort,compress]{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs,chemformula}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\newenvironment{figurehere}

%{\def\@captype{figure}}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-0.05in}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}

  \centering

  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}

    \toprule

    Year  & Journal    & Paper & Description& Attack Type \\
    \midrule
    
    {1995} & Journal of Moderen optics & et al. Phoenix \cite{phoenix1995multi} & \makecell {proposed technique to allow multi-user secure key distribution \\ on optical networks} & Eavesdropping \\
    
  {1997} & IEEE network & et al. Medard \cite{medard1997security} & \makecell {Provide overview of physical layer security about tapping \\ and eavesdropping attacks in optical passive network} & Survey Paper \\
 \ch{2019} 
    & \makecell {Optics express} & et al. Li \cite{li2019optical} & \makecell {In order to detect attacks, this paper studies the optical spectral signature analysis (OSFA) and recognition. By analyzing the spectral characteristics of optical signals, the identification and detection of unauthorized signals can be realized} & \makecell {Attack Management} \\

     
ch{2019} 
    & \makecell {Journal of Lightwave Technology} & et al. Natalino \cite{natalino2019experimental} & \makecell {This paper proposes a machine learning (ML) framework for detecting and identifying physical layer attacks. The framework is based on experimental attack trajectories from the operator site of testers deployed with coherent receivers, and performs in-band and out-of-band interference Signal insertion attacks, and polarization scrambling attacks of different intensities} & \makecell {Attack Management} \\

ch{2019} 
    & \makecell {-} & et al. Bensalem \cite{bensalem2019machine} & \makecell {This paper proposes a machine learning (ML) framework for detecting and preventing jamming attacks in optical networks, and proposes a novel resource redistribution scheme that uses statistical information on the accuracy of attack detection to reduce successful congestion The probability of the light path while minimizing the redistribution of the light path} & \makecell {Attack Management} \\

ch{2020} 
    & \makecell {Journal of Lightwave Technology} & et al. Furdek \cite{furdek2020machine} & \makecell {The framework includes modules for detecting and identifying attacks. These modules can use supervised, semi-supervised, and unsupervised learning to detect attacks, and when applicable, identify the type and strength of the attack; and the connection and/or link local for the attack Modified modules have been integrated into NMS} & \makecell {Attack Detecting and Identifying} \\

     

    \bottomrule

  \end{tabular}

  \caption{Sample table}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What is the purpose of the \ch command here?

Comment: According to its documentation, the IEEEtran documentclass expect table captions above the table rather than below it.